# Interoperability of C# and C++ (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call C# dll function from Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818136/call-c-dll-function-from-visual-c)

I have a set of C# classes. Can I import these classes in a C++ project like libraries and use them in this new project?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to reference the dll.

You said C++/CLI, correct?